# LED lights question

Tags: discussion

https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/24309/led-lights-on-same-switch

How do you deal with getting a question like this migrated to us?

This is a chat exchange with CDE who followed the question from EE to comment.

@DucatiKiller because one mod is exceptionally migrate happy. Mention car 12V? migrate here. Mention arduino? Migrated. Mention RPI? Migrated. Regardless of what the question asks or anything. – cde 37

CDE has 29K rep on electrical engineering.

This really seems like an EE question so what do you do, migrate back and forth and have a migration war?  Then the OP suffers and this guy seems like he's along for the ride.  Odd thing.

So, what do you do in this situation?

Comment: Good question - I've noticed the same thing, lots of questions from EE migrated just because they mention the word 'car' or 'vehicle' - this one in particular is much more suited to EE than here. I think that SE needs some way for the recipient site to control migration - so that our mods could refuse a question with a "no, it should stay where it is" response...

Comment: Perhaps someone should post the same question with "vehicle" replaced by "kitchen" and see if he migrates it to the cooking SE ;)

Comment: I'm wondering if that is something @JonEricson could help with?

Comment: @NickC: The target site can reject a migration by closing the question.

Comment: @NickC more like DIY/Home Improvement because it mentioned house wiring.

Comment: I'm most active on EE and have to agree. Even if a question really really belongs there, it is often migrated due to a key word. That question is a pure EE question and could be answered there, especially as EE has a nice built-in schematic editor we don't have here. Finally, we at MV.EE could delegate everything to EE, engineering, chemistry and a couple of software-SEs.

Comment: @JonEricson : When the target side closes the question, is it really rejected back to the first site, i.e. it appears there again? I'd think my question is first migrated and then closed which is not.. nice.

Comment: @sweber yes, with a migration rejection notice. Most often it stays closed. That's why these willy nilly migrations are a problem.